# Sequence - GCD(a,b)>1

Tags: algorithms, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Make an algorithm (the quickest way) for a sequence ($a_n$) of natural number defined as follow:$a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $\ldots$ , $a_n= gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)>1$. 
We asking about an index of any number for example: 
5 -> 10
332 -> 312

Comment: What do you mean by $a_n=(a_{n-1},a_n)<1$? that's a cycle in the definition and the gcd is $\geq 1$. Isnt it?

Comment: Then by induction necessarily $a_n=2$ for $n\ge 2$.